# Access denied when launching WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce, .net-4.6.2

We have a problem when launching WPF application that's been distributed via ClickOnce. Users that have this problem recently updated to .NET 4.6.2, but application itself is built and compiled under 4.5.2. But it installs ok as you can see from the log, so that's not the problem. Users run Windows 7.
Here's the error we got:

```
 PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1076.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/lpiter/OneDrive%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0/appname.application
    Deployment Provider url     : http://xyz.servername.com/appname/appname/appname.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    Application url         : http://appname.servername.com/appname/appname/client/appname.exe.manifest
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/8.0

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : appname.app, Version=1.6.5.888, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : appname.exe, Version=1.6.5.888, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\lpiter\OneDrive xyz\appname.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Activation failed.
        + Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:14] : Activation of C:\Users\lpiter\OneDrive xyz\appname.application has started.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:14] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:14] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:14] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:15] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:15] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:15] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:15] : Installation of application has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [09.08.2016 11:46:15] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Activation)
        - Activation failed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.UnauthorizedAccessException
        - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    * Transaction at [09.08.2016 11:46:15]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: RRDOMQQP.Q7Y.application
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0
```

Any ideas on what's that about and how to fix it? Removing and installing application doesn't help, and rolling back to 4.5.2 doesn't help either.

Comment: Well, you got Access Denied error, maybe you don't launch it as admin or you don't have the right privileges

Comment: @OrMiz tried launching as admin - same story

Comment: Do the other users on the network have a direct access to this file? Try to launch the exe file through the network

Comment: @OrMiz I don't follow - app is downloaded from the url and installed from local folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that antivirus software blocked the application for some reason (two separate programs actually, Kaspersky and Avast). After adding our app to a whitelist the problem has vanished.

Comment: You should accept your own answers so others can see the problem is solved